# Text inside of divs causing unwanted spacing

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.

I get a top space inside the left div above  `<h2>Nav</h2>` and another on top of the right div above `<h2>Title</h2>` I am not sure why and these spaces are not wanted. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="leftSide" >
      <h2>Nav</h2>
       <a href = "http://www.****.com/" class="txtLinks">Internal Link</a>
       <a href = "http://www.****.com/" class="txtLinks">No Follow Link</a>
       <a href = "http://www.****.com/" class="txtLinks">New Window Link</a>
    </div> 
    <div id="rightSide" >
       <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
width: 955px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftSide
{
float: left;
padding-left:0px;
background-color: #D3D3D3;
width: 190px;
height: 579px;
border-right: 1px solid Black;
}

#rightSide
{
margin-left: 191px;
width: 764px;
height: 579px;
background-color: Green;
}

.txtLinks
{
padding-left: 35px;   
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the default top/bottom margin that appears on all header elements - just add:

```
h2 {
margin: 0;
}
```

Consider using a [reset](http://cssreset.com) in your stylesheet to remove all of the default UA styles